# Is it possible to create my own unchecked Exception in Java?

Tags: java, error-handling

Is it possible to create my own unchecked exception in Java?

Basically, I'd like to

- Have my own exception class, `MyUncheckedException`
- That does not make me update all methods that call the method that throws this exception with a flood of own `throws`

Comment: Just beware that adding new exceptions to existing code basically breaks compatibility with prior versions of your API. Sure, if you only add RuntimeExceptions it's still binary compatible, but personally I consider that even worse: Unaware people will now link to the new version and suddenly get strange errors.. ugh.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. Extend `MyUncheckedException` from [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). However, below is the **guideline** from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

> Generally speaking, do not throw a RuntimeException or create a
>   subclass of RuntimeException simply because you don't want to be
>   bothered with specifying the exceptions your methods can throw.
>
> Here's the bottom line guideline: If a client can reasonably be
>   expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If
>   a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an
>   unchecked exception.

Comment: What would the code to do this look like? Are you able to show code to extend from `RuntimeException`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes - derive it from [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)

Make sure that you do it for the right reason: as a rule, runtime exceptions indicate *programming errors*, rather than errors that a program could potentially react to in some meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just wanting to subclass RuntimeException?

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave an example here, just in case:

```
public class MyCustomException extends RuntimeException {

    public MyCustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

YES. According to Effective Java -

> While the Java Language Specification does not require it, there is a strong
>   convention that errors are reserved for use by the JVM to indicate resource deficiencies, invariant failures, or other conditions that make it impossible to continue execution. Given the almost universal acceptance of this convention, it’s best not to implement any new Error subclasses. Therefore, all of the unchecked throwables you implement should subclass RuntimeException (directly or indirectly).

Below usage of unchecked exception is recommended :-

1. Use runtime exceptions to indicate programming errors.
2. If you believe a condition is likely to allow for recovery, use a checked exception; if not, use a runtime exception. If it isn’t clear whether recovery is possible, you’re probably better off using an unchecked exception.

About documenting unchecked exception -

> Use the Javadoc @throws tag to document each unchecked exception that
>   a method can throw, but do not use the throws keyword to include unchecked
>   exceptions in the method declaration.